# how the autocomplete widget works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am new to this jquery, So please help me to know the details about autocomplete widget process with example. could you please help me? thanks in advance..

Comment: Read documentation, and it has a working example: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

Comment: Google is your best friend, if you are stuck google it, failing that ask on stack, googling jquery ajax autocomplete will give you more than enough resources.

Comment: -1. There are about a dozen examples on the website and plenty more on Google. Did you search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find demo and documentation on below given link..

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

All the best